# Multiple awk programs in one go

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

Say for data file sampleTest1.dat

```
Type,^*p,Pl@nt_!d,C^*mp@nyC^*de,S@P_Pr^*f!t_Center,USF_BrC^*de,D!v_Nbr,N@meSh^*rt,N@mePr^*per,@ddress1,@ddress2,_C!ty,Reg!^*n,P^*st@lC^*de,C^*untry,Ph^*ne,@C_Type,Sh@red_Fl@g_@C
@C,1,1220,1410,US0001,,,J@CKS^*N,"_ J@CKS^*N, LLC",44 M!LW@UKEE STREET,,J@CKS^*N,MS,320683,US@,60135411,B,Y
@C,3,1225,1400,US0003,,,J@CKS^*NV!LLE,"_ J@CKS^*NV!LLE, !NC.",15 LEW!S !NDUSTR!@L R^*@D,,J@CKS^*NV!LLE,FL,32540000,US@,,B,Y
@C,4,1095,1400,US0004,,,CENTR@@#L C@L!F^*RN!@,"_ CENTR@L C@L!F^*RN!@, !NC.",13 M@R!P^*S@ R^*@D,,M^*DEST^*,C@,95340000,US@,,B,Y
@C,5,1210,1400,US0005,,,!NTERM*UNT@!N,"_ !NTERM^*UNT@!N, !NC.",949 S^*UTH PR^*SPER!TY,,WEST J^*RD@N,UT,8408100,US@,,,N
@C,6,1150,1400,US0006,,,N^*RTH# &EX@S,"_ N^*RTH TEX@S, !NC.",80 TR!N!TY DR!VE,P.^*. B^*X 561000,LEW!SV!LLE,TX,7560000,US@,4646000,,N
```

Now for this data clearly you can see the delimiter is ','

now what i want to do is

- the special characters to be removed except for _
- use camel-case eg for texas -> Texas
- for $5 (field no 5) i wanna use 8 padding except for 001,002,005 eg. for the value 003 -> 00000003
- concatenate $1 & $2 with '_' in between eg. type row -> type_row

So that the output data looks like for first two line:

```
Type_P,Plntd,CmpnyCde,SP_Prft_Center,USF_BrCde,Dv_Nbr,NmeShrt,NmePrper,Ddress1,Ddress2,_Cty,Regn,PstCde,Cuntry,Phne,C_Type,Shred_Flg_C
C_1,1220,1410,US00000001,,,JCKSN,_JCKSN, LLC,44 MLWUKEE STREET,,JCKSN,MS,320683,US,60135411,B,Y
```

I have almost all the programs:

To remove the special character

```
sed 's/[!@#\$%^&*()]//g' filename
```

For camel case

```
{   text = $0;
    split(text, words, /[^a-zA-Z]+/);
    for (i=1; i<=length(words); i++) {
        res = res toupper(substr(words[i],1,1)) tolower(substr(words[i],2));
    }
    print res
}
```

For 8 padding

```
sed 's/[^,][^,]*/\n0000000&/2;s/\n[^,]*\(.\{8\}\),/\1,/' inputfile
```

For appending the `_` we can always use:

```
{print $1 "_" $2}
```

So my question is: is there any other way i can pipe all these in one go? Or any other way. but please limit the answer with awk and sed only.

Comment: This sounds like a big bunch of things to do. Some are hard but some are trivial: what have you done so far to solve [at least] the trivial ones? This would be a good starting point, otherwise it looks like you want us to do everything :)

Comment: i have got all the programs. for example for cample case {   text = $0;
    split(text, words, /[^a-zA-Z]+/);
    for (i=1; i<=length(words); i++) {
        res = res toupper(substr(words[i],1,1)) tolower(substr(words[i],2));
    }
    print res
}

Comment: Please do use the edit button to append this valuable information.

Comment: for removing special charecter sed 's/[!@#\$%^&*()]//g' filename
but the problem is i cannot join all them in a single program file.. as it will resolve the complexity of calling them one by one... i will update the question once again

Comment: Note the first sed can be converted into awk by saying `gsub(/)?.../,"")` and the second using `sprintf`. By using the first awk code (the long one) and adding this together with the `print $1 _ $2` should be enough.

Comment: the reply (not teh one you want) is yes and with a awk or a sed and without needing a piped series. Could you tell in wich context (OS/Shell (GNU/posix sed ?)  it should works, sed is depending of that)

Comment: Random letters and spaces are missing from your output e.g `Pstcode` should be `Pstlcode` and `_JCKSN` should be `_ JCKSN` and also non of the second line is camel case so i don't know what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted expected output doesn't match your posted input, nor does it match your stated requirements so this is just a guess but maybe this is what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:]_,]/,"")
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        split($i,a,/ /)
        $i = ""
        for (j=1;j in a;j++) {
            $i = $i (j>1?" ":"") toupper(substr(a[j],1,1)) tolower(substr(a[j],2))
        }
    }
    match($5,/[[:digit:]]/)
    $5 = substr($5,1,RSTART-1) sprintf("%08d",substr($5,RSTART))
    sub(/,/,"_")
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Type_P,Plnt_d,Cmpnycde,00000000,Usf_brcde,Dv_nbr,Nmeshrt,Nmeprper,Ddress1,Ddress2,_cty,Regn,Pstlcde,Cuntry,Phne,C_type,Shred_flg_c
C_1,1220,1410,Us00000001,,,Jcksn,_ Jcksn, Llc,44 Mlwukee Street,,Jcksn,Ms,320683,Us,60135411,B,Y
C_3,1225,1400,Us00000003,,,Jcksnvlle,_ Jcksnvlle, Nc,15 Lews Ndustrl Rd,,Jcksnvlle,Fl,32540000,Us,,B,Y
C_4,1095,1400,Us00000004,,,Centrl Clfrn,_ Centrl Clfrn, Nc,13 Mrps Rd,,Mdest,C,95340000,Us,,B,Y
C_5,1210,1400,Us00000005,,,Ntermuntn,_ Ntermuntn, Nc,949 Suth Prsperty,,West Jrdn,Ut,8408100,Us,,,N
C_6,1150,1400,Us00000006,,,Nrth Exs,_ Nrth Texs, Nc,80 Trnty Drve,P Bx 561000,Lewsvlle,Tx,7560000,Us,4646000,,N
```

If not, fix your desired output to clarify.

Comment: This doesn't camel case after `_`'s as shown in OPs example, but then again half the stuff in the example doesn't match their requirements so maybe it shouldn't

Comment: Right, it also may or may not match the OPs definition of "special" when deciding which "special characters" to remove. I really don't know what the OP wants but hopefully this is simple enough to follow that (s)he can just modify it to suit, or they'll post the real expected output given that input and then we can help them. For now I've tweaked it to not treat spaces as "special characters" and camel-case the space-separated words within fields. Thanks for the idea.